# WinAPI - Determine if a window has maximize/restore capability

Tags: java, c#, c++, windows, winapi

Problem: Determining if a window (by, say, hWnd) has the capability of being maximized or restored. Purpose of this is to programmatically send maximize/restore events to windows (for automation) but exclude windows which can't handle it.

Please consider the following two example windows while trying to determine this from [GetWindowLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx) with GWL_STYLE:

---

a) The Discord client app (it is built with Electron). It has styles:

- WS_CAPTION
- WS_SIZEBOX

It does **NOT** have styles:

- WS_SYSMENU
- WS_MAXIMIZEBOX

This window does display a restore/maximize button and behaves properly when SW_MAXIMIZE/SW_RESTORE are posted to it.

---

b) The "Are you sure you want to quit?" prompt in InteliJ IDEA. It has styles:

- WS_CAPTION
- WS_SIZEBOX
- WS_SYSMENU

It does **NOT** have style:

- WS_MAXIMIZEBOX

This window does NOT display a restore/maximize button and does NOT behave properly when SW_MAXIMIZE/SW_RESTORE are posted to it (it crashes the whole IDE).

---

So, given these two examples, the following facts are true:

1) A window **with** WS_SIZEBOX style **may not** respond to SW_MAXIMIZE/SW_RESTORE messages properly (wasn't designed to);

2) A window **without** WS_SYSMENU nor WS_MAXIMIZEBOX **may still** respond to SW_MAXIMIZE/SW_RESTORE messages properly (draws system menu and/or buttons itself in a non-standard way)

3) Both of them have a native system menu that opens via title bar secondary-click and they correctly list maximize/restore as enabled or disabled (whatever matches their capability).

Given those two facts, **how do I actually determine if a window can or cannot handle being maximized/restored**? It seems it is not possible from window style alone, but I can't find anything in the <s>Win32 API</s> WinAPI to do this.

Note that I am deciding on whether to send SW_MAXIMIZE/SW_RESTORE by calling [GetWindowPlacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518(v=vs.85).aspx) and checking the showCmd.

Also note that I am using Java/JNA but I understand C++ or C# perfectly fine if you want to share code snippets.

Comment: Maximize/restore capability is determined by the way the window proc deals with `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message containing `SC_MAXIMIZE` and `SC_RESTORE` flags. Presence of `WS_SIZEBOX` or `WS_MAXIMIZE` only allows a default behavior to be applied by default window proc. "it crashes the whole IDE" sound like a bug.

Comment: So I need to somehow find out is if the window can handle the SC_MAXIMIZE or SC_RESTORE messages? I see there's a GetSystemMenu function, but I'll keep digging for a better way than probing the menu (which may not work in the case of the Discord/Electron window for all I know).

Comment: I don't think that there is any reliable way to do so. Window proc can be changed by application or the behavior regarding `WM_SYSCOMMAND` may vary depending on application state.

Comment: Of course neither one has `WS_MAXIMIZE`, because that means *"The window is **initially** maximized"*. Perhaps you should check `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` instead, which means *"The window has a maximize button"*. You linked to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx), but did you read it?

Comment: @VTT You're probably right. It does seem I can use GetSystemMenu > GetMenuState to manually check if the Maximize/Restore is enabled or disabled, but it's not possible for me to do this on my EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND callback (I think it's too early). But yes that's not guaranteed to be reliable - seems I will probably have to just handle per-app special cases.

Comment: @Andreas sorry, those are typo's. Edited. I did indeed mean the WS_MAXIMIZEBOX style. Discord/Electron has no WS_MAXIMIZEBOX style nor WS_SYSMENU style, despite the fact that it does have a sysmenu and can respond to maximize/restore messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that as a last resort I can use GetSystemMenu > GetMenuItemInfo to check if either Restore or Maximize system menu entry is enabled. So this is a decent fallback if the window has no WS_MAXIMIZEBOX style for whatever reason.